# Share changes via push or pull?

Tags: git, version-control

When I want to share  local changes so they are available for other users / in other branches, my understanding is, that I have two possible ways:

1. I can push from my local branch to the corresponding remote branch.
   e.g. from local/dev to remote/dev
   Then I can checkout another branch (e.g. new_branch) and use

   `git pull origin dev` to update local/new_branch
   and then push to remote/new_branch.
2. Maybe I don't need the remote/dev. I would then push directly from local/dev to remote/new_branch. And any other users can checkout new_branch and then use

   `git pull origin new_branch` to update their local/new_branch

Can anyone tell me if this is correct and if there is a difference in the result. Which method is preferable? Is there another way to do this?

[image share changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ecuAr.png)

Comment: Everything you have said involves migrating all changes from your branch to the new one; not just the one commit.  Is that what you want to do, or are you really interested in the one commit?

Comment: You don't need a remote at all to checkout/merge/push/pull/rebase/cherry-pick between local branches. Can be done completely offline.

Comment: Sorry, got that wrong. I want to migrate all changes not only one commit. But the changes should be available not only in my local branches, but for other users as well.

Comment: `When I want to share a local commit so it's available for other branches` What's your point of sharing your work (your commits) ?

Comment: This question is really not clear. Please state what your trying to achieve not how you think you should achieve this. I'm pretty sure your making some incorrect assumptions here

Comment: I am working on branch dev. At some point my work should be available in another branch ("new_branch" as an example). Other users need access to my changes and they pull from "new_branch". So do I push from local/dev to remote/new_branch or do I checkout new_branch, then pull from remote/dev and then push to remote/new_branch?

Comment: Has the new_branch been present on the remote before? If not, you can skip pull. If you don’t want the things to get too complicated, you should keep the names of tracking branches in your local repo same as the names in the remote repo. Git supports the opposite though.

Comment: A branch can’t be a remote. 

Comment: new_branch exists on remote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can **push local `dev` branch into remote `new_branch` directly**.

Before pushing, you should **compare the local `dev` branch with remote `new_branch`** with below commands:

```
git fetch origin new_branch
git log dev..origin/new_branch --oneline
```

If the output of `git log dev..origin/new_branch --oneline` command shows commits, that means, remote `new_branch` contains the commits that does not exist on your local `dev` branch. Else (output shows no commits), you can push local `dev` into `new_branch` directly as below option 2.

You can follow any of below options based on your situation, when some changes on `new_branch` does not exist on your local `dev` branch (the output shows commits):

#### Option 1: Get all the changes from new_branch to local dev branch

And if you want to apply the changes from remote `new_branch` into your local `dev` branch, you can use below commands:

```
git checkout dev
git pull origin new_branch
git push origin dev:newbranch
```

#### Option 2: push dev into new_branch by discarding some changes

And if you want to push local `dev` branch into `new_branch` by discarding the changes which does not exist on your local dev branch, you can execute below commands:

```
git checkout dev
git push origin dev:new_branch -f
```

Comment: Thanks for the helpful answer !!

Answer (score 0):

Let me summarize the current situation:

- You are developing on the local `dev` branch.
- There is the remote branch `new_branch`.
- The changes from your local `dev` should be pushed to `new_branch`.
- Your local `dev` and `new_branch` are both based on `master` but have diverged (neither of them contains all commits of the other one).

In this case, you should `rebase` changes in your `dev` onto the current state of `new_branch`.

```
git checkout new_branch
git pull
git rebase new_branch dev
```

You should use the [`merge`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge) and [`rebase`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) commands which are intended for what you are trying to achieve. Trying to achieve the same using `pull` is not the best option (it [does `merge`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/292359/711006) though), at least it prevents you from doing the merge offline.